# Прокрутка в Expander

Tags: c#, wpf

Есть несколько `Expander` и у одного из них должен быть прокручивающийся контент.

Проблема в том, что прокрутка работает только если не указывать жестко размеры строки, но если указать `Height=Auto`, прокрутка отказывается работать.

В то же время, если не указать размер строки как `Auto`, то `Expander` растягивается на остальное пространство.

Как найти компромисс?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander Grid.Row="0"
        Background="LightBlue" Header="1" Margin="10"/>
    <Expander Grid.Row="1"
        Background="LightBlue" Header="2" Margin="10">
        <ScrollViewer>

        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Comment: Установите MaxHeight контенту?

Comment: @VladD, Так ведь это нераскрытый `Expander` растягивается.

Comment: А, ну да. А почему у вас вторая строка не Auto?

Comment: @VladD, Потому что тогда `ScrollViewer` не работает.

Comment: А если Auto и MaxHeight? `<RowDefinition Height="Auto" MaxHeight="100"/>`?

Comment: @VladD, Тогда `Expander` не раскрывается на всю свободную область, а контент не прокручивается.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну например так. Сделаем, чтобы распахнутому экспандеру доставалась звёздочка, а свёрнутому — `Auto`. Для этого понадобится простой конвертер:

```
class BooleanConverter<T> : IValueConverter
{
    public T OnTrue { get; set; }
    public T OnFalse { get; set; }

    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        ((bool)value) ? OnTrue : OnFalse;

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object p, CultureInfo ci) =>
        object.Equals(OnTrue, value);
}

class BooleanToGridLengthConverter : BooleanConverter<GridLength> { }
```

Ну и XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:BooleanToGridLengthConverter OnTrue="*" OnFalse="Auto" x:Key="B2GL"/>
</Window.Resources>

<!-- ... -->

<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=First,
                                   Converter={StaticResource B2GL}}"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="{Binding IsExpanded, ElementName=Second,
                                   Converter={StaticResource B2GL}}"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <Expander Grid.Row="0" Name="First">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Height="400">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Red" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Yellow" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
    <Expander Grid.Row="1" Name="Second">
        <ScrollViewer>
            <Grid Height="400">
                <Grid.Background>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="Blue" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Color="Green" Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Grid.Background>
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </Expander>
</Grid>
```

Результат:

[image: ну как бы вот так]